# is there a way to increase TextField password dot icon much bigger in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, android-compose-textfield

I am doing Password Textfield and I want to do password dot when user typing but default password dot icon is small I want to bigger Textfield password dot. How can I do that ?

hear is my TextFiedl code ->

```
  var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
  var isFocused by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
  val color = if (isFocused || text.isNotEmpty()) DefaultDYTColor else Color.Transparent

     TextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .border(
                    width = if (isFocused) 1.dp else 0.dp,
                    color = color,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp)
                )
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(25.dp))
                .onFocusChanged {
                    isFocused = it.isFocused
                },
            value = text,
            onValueChange = { newText ->
                text = newText
            },
            visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(),
            leadingIcon = {
                Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_password), contentDescription = "" )
            },
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                cursorColor = MaterialTheme.colors.DYTThemeColor,
                disabledTextColor = Color.Transparent,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default mask for `PasswordVisualTransformation` is a bullet point `•` or `\u2022` in code style. You can replace the mask with any unicode character by declaring it as constructor parameter.

For example, `PasswordVisualTransformation(mask = '\u25CF')` will apply a black circle `●` as a mask.

```
TextField(
    ...
    visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(mask = '\u25CF'),
    ...
)
```

Happy coding!